# How to return Yes or No if nested query has result or not in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, subquery

I have a stored procedure with a nested query that checks whether "`category`" from the main table matches a "`category`" in a sub table. 
So there can either be one match or none.

How can I return Yes if there is a match and the sub query returns something and No if there is no match and the sub query returns nothing ?

I tried the following which works in general but only if there is a match as otherwise this returns nothing.

**My SQL (shortened):**

```
SELECT      A.categoryID,
            A.category,
            A.[description],
            (
                SELECT      'Yes' AS subscribed
                FROM        MOC_Categories_Subscribers D
                WHERE       D.category = A.category
                FOR XML PATH(''), ELEMENTS, TYPE
            )
FROM        MOC_Categories A
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If subquery doesn't return any rows then your result will be NULL. Thus you need to check it. In SQL Server you can do this by using functions [`ISNULL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx) and [`COALESCE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx), it depends on version that you're using

```
SELECT A.categoryID,
       A.category,
       A.[description],
       COALESCE((SELECT TOP 1 'Yes'
                 FROM MOC_Categories_Subscribers D
                 WHERE D.category = A.category), 'No') AS Result
FROM MOC_Categories A
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT      A.categoryID,
            A.category,
            A.[description],
            (
                SELECT      
                case 
                   when count(subscribed) > 0 then 'Yes'
                   else 'No'
                end
                FROM        MOC_Categories_Subscribers D
                WHERE       D.category = A.category
            )
FROM        MOC_Categories A
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `outer join`, which returns `null` values if there is no match. Combine with a `case` to convert to a yes/no value:

```
SELECT  A.categoryID,
        A.category,
        A.[description],
        subscribed = CASE
           WHEN D.category IS NOT NULL THEN 'Yes'
           ELSE 'No'
           END,
FROM        MOC_Categories A
LEFT OUTER JOIN MOC_Categories_Subscribers D
   ON D.category = A.category
```

Comment: In this case semantic of query will be different. If we have an association one to many a result will double

Comment: True, but the OP specified "one or none" in this case.